# What does the letter 'u' mean in umask?

Tags: history, umask, terminology, historical-unix

Is it "user mask" or something?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) does not have details, but says the feature has been in Unix since 1978.

POSIX just says it is the "file mode creation mask".

Comment: u = user g=group o=others

Comment: @admstg the wrong `u`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a long-standing explanation, exemplified by [this entry in Wolfram Rosler's list](http://www.roesler-ac.de/wolfram/acro/credits.htm#7), that it means "user".  That entry was submitted in 2000, and attributes it to the fact that the "umask" set a `U_cmask` field in the process' "`u` area".

This is a somewhat dubious explanation, the doubt acknowledged in the original by it being put in the form of a question, because there are several other things in the "`u` area", all of whose fields were conventionally named `u_something`, that are not set by system calls begining with "u".  It is possible that it is a rationalization two decades after the fact.

That the "u" stands for "user" is, on the other hand, widely accepted nowadays, and was widely accepted back in 2000, even though the "`u` area" explanation for that is dubious.  Books about UNIX have described the `umask` as the "user file creation mask" since the late 1980s (although none of them make any mention of the "`u` area").

- It's described that way in the printed manuals for AT&T Unix System 5 Release 3.
- It's described that way in the 1989 X/Open *Portability Guide*.
- It's described that way in Peter Norton's 1991 *Guide to Unix*.
- Simson Garfinkel's and Gene Spafford's 1991 *Practical UNIX Security* explicitly outright says

  > umask (UNIX shorthand for "user file-creation mode mask")

The problem is that the word "user" in the expansion of the name doesn't occur in works before 1985.  The earliest that I have been able to find is Rebecca Thomas' 1985 *A user guide to the UNIX system*, followed by "`umask` (user mask)" in the Andersons' 1986 *The UNIX C Shell Field Guide*.

- Stephen R. Bourne's 1983 *The UNIX System* has a collection of manual entries for 7th Edition UNIX.  The one for the `umask()` system call on page 294 does not contain the word "user" anywhere, just calling it a "file creation mode mask".  The one for `sh` makes no mention of the subject at all.
- The 1983 *Unix Time-Sharing System: Unix Programmer's Manual* from Bell Labs repeats Bourne's wording (which is to be expected):

  > NAME umask — set file creation mode mask
  >
  > SYNOPSIS
  > `umask(complmode)`
  >
  > DESCRIPTION
  > Umask sets a mask used whenever a file is created by `creat`(T) or `mknod`(2): […]
- On the BSD side of the universe, the 1987 *UNIX Programmer's Reference Manual (PRM): 4.3 Berkeley Software Distribution, Virtual VAX-11 Version* also makes no mention of the word "user":

  > NAME umask — set file creation mode mask
  >
  > SYNOPSIS
  > `oumask = umask(numask) int oumask, numask;`
  >
  > DESCRIPTION
  > Umask sets the process's file mode creation mask to `numask` and returns the previous value of the mask. […]
- There's no "user" in Marc J. Rochkind's 1985 *Advanced UNIX programming*, just "file mode creation mask".
- Nor in the Waite Group's 1987 *Unix System V Bible* ("file-creation mask").

It has been widely accepted for the better part of 4 decades that the "u" stands for "user"; but it's hard to trace that back to the initial coinage of the name, the linkage to the "`u` area" only appears two decades after the fact, the word "user" seems to have appeared at some point between 7th Edition UNIX and AT&T Unix System 5 Release 3, and that word may have been introduced after the fact as a seemingly reasonable expansion for "u" by people writing formal doco.

## Further reading

- [So what was the "u area" in UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/583316/5132)

Comment: An absolutely exemplary answer in every respect. Thank you very much for your dedication.

Comment: Oh. my.. god... it stands for *use*! Hit me when I was looking at that old manual quote: "Umask sets a mask *used* whenever a file is created" (emphasis added). "umask 027"->"use mask 027". I could be wrong, but for several reasons "user" doesn't quite add up (appears much later, no good explanation, other syscalls/commands having to do with the user(/user area) don't use "u" prefix, and conceptually it's just a tad of a weird fit for what it does), while "use" appears in the first manpage, perfectly says what you are telling the system to do, and matches all the other abbreviated verb naming.

Comment: (But if I'm right and it's "use" rather than "user", why didn't they use `s` for `set`, like they did in `stty`, `stime`, `smdate`, and so on? I think it's because conceptually, when you're setting parameters on a terminal, the time on the system, or the date on a file, you are setting external state which is potentially shared by, and more persistent than, "you" (the process)... it's not something you are *using* as much as just a change you make in the world and step away from... meanwhile the file mode creation mask is *used* by a lot more operations that a typical process typically does.)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in `man umask`, but in bash `help umask` says `Sets the user file-creation mask to MODE.` While this is incorrect: it sets the process's file-creation mask to MODE. It shows that the `u` **may** stand for user. This what I was told back in 1991.

Comment: While your remark is correct and on point, maybe they meant it as the "user mask" in the sense that if you set the process mask in your login shell, all the processes you launch from that shell will inherit the mask :) Anyway, thanks for adding another data point in favor of "user".

Comment: The `u` _could_ also be for "update" (the `umask` utility updates the file creation mask), but that's just pure speculation, and not very likely true.  I checked the V7 Unix sources and manual, but they were not helpful.

Comment: It is worth remembering that the umask and ulimits were stored in a "`u` area".

Comment: @JdeBP Do you know whether the `u` area was originally per-user or per-process?

Comment: If you don't know what the `u` area was, you should ask a question.  (-:  It's worth a question and answer in its own right, and seems to have 1 tangential mention in the whole of this WWW site.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/583316/5132 now exists.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor You need to check the right man pages. Linux man pages are known to be bad in many cases.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think you got closer than most. I think it was initially meant to stand for the *verb* "use", not the noun "user". The first manpage explicitly uses the verb "use" in the past tense: "Umask sets a mask used whenever a file is created by ...". And we can see from the manpages from back then that it was typical for UNIX system calls and commands to be verbs or verb-based phrases (and for those verbs to be abbrevated, sometimes down to just one character - for example "s" for "set" was common: `stty` (set tty), `stime` (set time), `smdate` (set modified date)).

Answer (score -6):

Calling `man umask` (on Solaris) gives the right answer:

```
...
  sh
 The user file-creation mode mask is set to ooo.   The  three
 octal  digits  refer  to  read/write/execute permissions for
 owner,  group,  and  other,  respectively   (see   chmod(1),
 chmod(2),  and umask(2)).  The value of each specified digit
...
```

So in some cases it is important to have a real UNIX to get better man pages.

Comment: Not sure whether this answers the question at all, or what makes the answer right, but it does also talk about the "user" file-creation mode mask.

Comment: Well, did you read the text? Your question was where does the "u" comes from? and my answer quotes a part from a UNIX man page that  calls it `user file-createion mode mask`. If you like to get a different answer, you would need to ask a different question.