# So what was the "u area" in UNIX?

Tags: kernel, historical-unix

The subject of the `u` area in UNIX came up [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583296/what-does-the-letter-u-mean-in-umask#comment1086157_583298).  So what was it?

Answer (score 39):

In AT&T Unix, and historically in the BSDs, there were only processes, not threads; and each entry in the process table comprised two parts, a `struct proc` structure and a `struct user` structure.  The former was always resident in kernel memory.  The latter could be swapped out, as part of swapping a process out.  (This is, remember, in the days where Unices actually *swapped* things, rather than *demand-paged* them.)

The `struct user` structure was also known as a the "u area".  This was because, as a consequence of some clever memory mapping, the current process's `user` structure was always at the same fixed virtual address in kernel memory, and could be referenced in code via the global symbol `u` (rather than through a pointer).

The structure contained all sorts of things that simply weren't needed by the kernel when a process was not the currently running process, including the file creation mask, the open file descriptor table, resource limits, and so on.  It contained the addresses of the signal *handlers*, only needed when the process is running and trying to invoke the handler, but not the mask of blocked signals or set of pending signals, both of which are needed when a process is swapped out and which were thus in the `struct proc`.  It even, in some Unices, contained the arguments for the current I/O operation, rather than have them be passed around on the stack.

Of course, the reasons for this design haven't held for a long time.  They were pretty much obsolete by the end of the 1980s.  The global variable and clever memory mapping ended up being replaced by simple indirection through a pointer after all.  You'll find that the `struct user` still exists in C library header files on the BSDs (in `<sys/user.h>`) but it is there largely for source compatibility.  [In XNU](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/a449c6a3b8014d9406c2ddbdc81795da24aa7443/bsd/sys/user.h#L381), it's actually declared as an empty structure.  [FreeBSD notes](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/e26092ad114e68e2318ad743e26c1d65278b0b10/sys/sys/user.h#L237) that it's present mainly because it is used in core dumps for a.out format executes.  Linux didn't even exist until after the idea was obsolete, and does not do things this way at all.

There was some variability in this design.  For example: AT&T Unix System 5 had an "extended user area", a `struct euser`, pointed to by the `u_euserp` field of the `u` structure, where some of the stuff lived.  This exemplifies a further point.  All of the member variables of the `struct user` are named `u_something` in line with the C kernel coding conventions of the time and its early language rules.  [This has been thought to be the reason that the `umask` is named as such](http://www.roesler-ac.de/wolfram/acro/credits.htm#7), although that is not certain.

## Further reading

- Steve D. Pate (1996).  *UNIX Internals: A Practical Approach*.  Addison-Wesley.  ISBN 9780201877212.
- Maurice J. Bach (1987). *The design of the Unix® operating system*. Prentice-Hall.  ISBN 0132017571.